# Mapping port between docker-compose and docker-compose.extend for development environment

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose` used for production which I'm hoping to incorporate with VS Code's dockerized development environment.

#### `./docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.6"
services:
  django: &django-base
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile_local
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/website
    depends_on:
      - memcached
      - postgres
      - redis
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - 8000:8000 # HTTP port
      - 3000:3000 # ptvsd debugging port
    expose:
      - "3000"
    env_file:
      - variables/django_local.env
   ...
```

Note how I'm both forwarding and exposing port `3000` here. This is a result of me playing around to get what I need working. Not sure if I need one or the other or both.

My `./devcontainer` then looks like the following:

#### `./devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "Dev Container",
    
    "dockerComposeFile": ["../docker-compose.yml", "docker-compose.extend.yml"],
    
    "service": "dev",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",

    "settings": { 
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": null,
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3.8"
    },

    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python"
    ]
}
```

#### `.devcontainer/docker-compose.extended.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    external_links:
      - django
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace:cached
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

The idea is that I want to be able to run VS code attached to the `dev` service, which from there I want to run the debugger attached to the `django` service using the following `launch.json` config:

```
{
    "name": "WP",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 3000,
    "host": "localhost",
    "pathMappings": [
        {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/website"
        }
    ]
},
```

I get an error when doing this though, where VS Code says `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`. How can I get the ports mapped so this will work? Is it even possible?

#### Edit

#### Why not just attach directly to the `django` service?

The dev container simply contains python and node runtimes for linting and intellisense purposes while using VS Code. The idea behind creating a new service devoted specifically to debugging in the dev environment is that `./docker-compose.yml` contains more than a few services that some of the devs on my team like to turn off sometimes to keep resource consumption low. By creating a container specifically for dev, it also makes it easier to setup `.devcontainer-devcontainer.json` to add things like extensions to one container without needing to add them after attaching to the running "non-dev" container. If this were to work, VS Code would be running within the `dev` container (see [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your ´dev´ service? What is its purpose? Are you running VS Code on your host or somehow in your Docker container? I'm not entirely sure why you don't attach VS Code straight to your Django container.

Comment: @MarcAndréFreiheit just added tot he "Edit" section. Hopefully that answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by changing the host in the `launch.json` from `localhost` to `host.docker.internal`. The resulting `launch.json` configuration then looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "WP",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 3000,
    "host": "host.docker.internal",
    "pathMappings": [
        {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/web-portal"
        }
    ]
},
```